# How to stop Manipulate changing view point

Tags: manipulate, visualization, plotting

When using the following manipulate I can rotate the plot and manipulate the value without my view point changing;

```
Manipulate[Plot3D[Sin[a*x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}], {a, 1, 5}]
```

If I rotate one of these plot in the following manipulate the value the view point changes back to the default.

```
Manipulate[GraphicsRow
[{Plot3D[Sin[a*x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}],
Plot3D[Sin[a*x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]}], 
{a, 1, 5}]
```

I have a much more complex plot that contains a GraphgicsRow and a Column and I want it to keep the view point of the plot while I manipulate it. Is there a simple way to do this? Is the problem the GraphicsRow or is that just a coincidence?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a strange feeling this question is a duplicate.  Does anyone recall?  Edit: I'm probably thinking of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8642182/618728

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GraphicsRow` is convenient to use, for example, when you would like to control the total width of many graphics or image objects with a single setting - because `GraphicsRow` takes `ImageSize` option. But there is no real reason to use it. Use `Row` instead  and control size of graphics individually for each plot:

```
Manipulate[Row[{
   Plot3D[Sin[a*x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 300],
   Plot3D[Sin[a*x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 300]}], {a, 1, 5}]
```

If you *must* use `GraphicsRow` or just curious how to make it work, here is a way - separate with `Dynamic`the options of internal `Plot3D`s so they do not reset each other. This maybe way to complicated and an overkill - but at least it is interesting:

```
Manipulate[GraphicsRow[{
   Graphics3D[Dynamic@Plot3D[Sin[a x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
       Boxed -> False, Axes -> False][[1]]],
   Graphics3D[Dynamic@Plot3D[Sin[a x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
       Boxed -> False, Axes -> False][[1]]]}], {a, 1, 5}]
```

You need `Graphics3D` because it can take `Dynamic` inside, but `Plot3D` cannot.

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy. It works when I replace the GraphicsRow with a Row.